# Как отменить скролл у боди оставив при этом скролл у pop-up окна?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

есть адаптивное pop-up окно, всё работает на десктопе, так как при всплытии окна отключается скролл у body, но проблема в том что на мобильных версиях скролл должен оставаться у самого pop-up окна так как для его просмотра на мобильной версии нужно будет его прокручивать, но у body не должно быть скролла чтобы пользователь не мог прокрутить pop-up, подскажите как можно реализовать скролл в pop-up окне без возможности скроллить основной контент?

```js
function popUp(popUpObject){
 let closeBtn = $('.bg-modal').find('.modal-contant__item2-close');
 let popUpObj = $(popUpObject);
 let openBtns = $('body').find('.popUpOpen');
 console.log(closeBtn);
 console.log(popUpObj);
 console.log(openBtns);
 

 closeBtn.on('click', function(){
  popUpObj.css('display', 'none');
  $('body').css('overflow', 'scroll');
 });

 openBtns.on('click', function(){
  popUpObj.css('display', 'flex');
  $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  if($('.burger-menu').hasClass('burger-menu__active')){
   $('.burger-menu').toggleClass('burger-menu__active');
  }
 });
}

popUp('.bg-modal');
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
const popUp = document.querySelector('.pop-up');
const toggle = document.querySelector('button');

toggle.addEventListener('click', toggle_pop_up)

function toggle_pop_up() {
  popUp.classList.toggle("hidden");
  document.body.style.overflowY = popUp.classList.contains("hidden") ? "scroll" : "hidden";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  right: 5%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.content {
  height: 3000px;
}

.pop-up {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid tomato;
}

.something {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 1rem;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button>toggle pop-up</button>

<div class="pop-up hidden">
  <div class="something"></div>
  <div class="something"></div>
  <div class="something"></div>
  <div class="something"></div>
</div>

<div class="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Приведу пример того, что использую я.

Здесь правда stylus вместо обычного css, Но думаю, что разобраться не составит труда.
Если не нравятся fadeIn и прочие жкверивские штуки, то легко можно заменить на обычное добавление\удаление класса.

```js
// Popup
$('.js-open-popup-btn').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.js-popup').fadeIn(300);
    $('html').addClass('is-fixed');
});


$('.js-close-popup-btn').on('click',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('.js-popup').fadeOut(300);
    $('html').removeClass('is-fixed');
});

$('.popup__overflow').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    var content = $(this).find('.popup__body');

    if(!content.is(e.target) && content.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $('html').removeClass('is-fixed');
        $('.js-popup').fadeOut(300);
    }

});
```

html
 &.is-fixed
 overflow hidden

.popup 
  position fixed
  top 50%
  left 50%
  transform translate(-50%, -50%
  z-index 90
  width 100%
  height 100%
  display none
  &__overflow
    position absolute
    left 0
    top 0
    width 100%
    backface-visibility hidden
    -webkit-backface-visibility hidden
    height 100%
    overflow auto
    box-sizing border-box
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling touch
    z-index 105
    background-color rgba(0,0,0, .7)
    padding 10px
    text-align center
    white-space nowrap
    &:before
      content ''
      display inline-block
      vertical-align middle
      width 0
      height 100%
    &__body
      width 100%
      max-width 380px
      background-color #fff
      padding 40px
      display inline-block
      vertical-align middle
      position relative
      white-space normal

```html
<!-- Popup stock-->
<div class="popup js-popup">
    <div class="popup__overflow">
        <div class="popup__body text-center">
            <button class="btn__close js-close-popup-btn" type="button"></button>
            <!-- Popup content-->
            <div class="popup__content">
                <h3 class="popup__title">Popup title</h3>
                <p class="popup__text">text</p>
            </div>
            <!-- //Popup content-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- //Popup -->
```